# How can i GROUP BY this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL query, and i've tried to many ways to group by, but it doesn't work for me, i want to group by **noExp**

```
select Alumnos.nombreComp as Nombre, 
       Carreras.nombre as Carrera, 
       Alumnos.noExp as Expediente, 
       Historial.fecha as Fecha, 
       Historial.equipo as Equipo 
from Alumnos, Historial, Carreras 
where YEAR(fecha)= @año 
  and MONTH (fecha)=@Mes 
  and Historial.noExp = Alumnos.noExp 
  and Alumnos.carrera = Carreras.id_carrera 
  and Alumnos.activo = 1
```

help!

Comment: `I want to group by noExp`, ok, and what do you want to do with the rest of the columns?

Comment: show the corresponding values

Comment: But you are grouping by one column, what would be the "corresponding" values for the rest?, the minimum?, maximum?, what?

Comment: So, i have to group all the columns?

Comment: I mean, how could I know?, I have no idea what your data looks like, and neither what you want as a result

Answer (score 2):

1. You should really use the correct join syntax `INNER JOIN` for getting matches between your tables and `OUTER JOIN` to get matches where there is a match but still get the records even when there is no match from one side.
2. To use GROUP BY you need an [Aggregate Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx), currently you do not have any and you make on mention of what type of aggregate you would like to see in your data so it would not make sense to add one.

Sql Code with correct join syntax

```
SELECT Alumnos.nombreComp as Nombre
    , Carreras.nombre as Carrera
    , Alumnos.noExp as Expediente
    , Historial.fecha as Fecha
    , Historial.equipo as Equipo 
FROM Alumnos INNER JOIN Historial ON Historial.noExp = Alumnos.noExp
    INNER JOIN Carreras ON Alumnos.carrera = Carreras.id_carrera 
WHERE YEAR(fecha)= @año 
    AND MONTH (fecha)=@Mes 
    AND Alumnos.activo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So with SQL Server you have to group by every column you mention in the select clause of your query. SQL Server needs to know how to organize all of your columns. If you would like to group by noExp then listing it as the first grouping option and then listing the subsequent columns in the group by in whichever order your data needs to appear in will get you a list that is primarily grouped by noExp.

```
select 
Alumnos.nombreComp as Nombre, 
Carreras.nombre as Carrera,
 Alumnos.noExp as Expediente, 
Historial.fecha as Fecha, Historial.equipo as Equipo 

from Alumnos, Historial, Carreras 
where YEAR(fecha)= @año 
and MONTH (fecha)=@Mes 
and Historial.noExp = Alumnos.noExp 
and Alumnos.carrera = Carreras.id_carrera 
and Alumnos.activo = 1
GROUP BY Alumnos.noExp, Alumnos.nombrecomp,Carreras.nombre,Historial.fecha
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by only one field than use MAX keyword and write query as below.

```
select MAX(Alumnos.nombreComp) as Nombre,
 MAX(Carreras.nombre) as Carrera, 
Alumnos.noExp as Expediente,
 Max(Historial.fecha) as Fecha,
 Max(Historial.equipo) as Equipo
 from Alumnos, Historial, Carreras 
where YEAR(fecha)= @año and MONTH (fecha)=@Mes
 and Historial.noExp = Alumnos.noExp 
and Alumnos.carrera = Carreras.id_carrera 
and Alumnos.activo = 1
GROUP By Alumnos.noExp
```

Answer (score 0):

for using group by clause you should a some Aggregate function in query like avg().use the aggregate function on field for which you want to use group by clause.